# Python network communication with encryption and password protection

Tags: python, encryption, https

I want to create a python program that can communicate with another python program running on another machine. They should communicate via network. For me, it's super simple using BasicHTTPServer. I just have to direct my message to http:// server2 : port /my/message and server2 can do whatever action needed based on that message "/my/message". It is also very time-efficient as I do not have to check a file every X seconds or something similar. (My other idea was to put text files via ssh to the remote server and then read that file..)

The downside is, that this is not password protected and not encrypted. I would like to have both, but still keep it that simple to transfer messages.

The machines that are communicating know each other and I can put key files on all those machines.

I also stumbled upon twisted, but it looks rather complicated. Also gevent looks way too complicated with gevent.ssl.SSLsocket, because I have to check for byte length of messages and stuff..

Is there a simple example on how to set something like this up?

Comment: You can try [CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have no problem rolling out a key file to all nodes ...

simply throw your messages into AES, and move the output like you moved the unencrypted messages ...

on the other side ... decrypt, and handle the plaintext like the messages you handled before ...

Comment: Not sure if a http server can handle a request like:
http: // server2 : port / \xd6\x83\x8dd!VT\x92\xaa`A\x05\xe0\x9b\x8b\xf1

Comment: you are not supposed to use HTTP GET to deliver a message like this ... use HTTP POST ... according to the HTTP protocol, GET should **never** change any information ... thats what POST is for... and of course POST can transfer binary data

Comment: As I just want to communicate from one program to the other, and no user will ever use a browser to check those URLs, I don't see a benefit in using POST instead of GET. But you are right about the fact that POST can transfer binary. I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure), as it does the job you want.

The good part is that you won't need to change the code as the connection between the two parties is encrypted. The downside is that you have to set up a server with an HTTP certificate (there are lot of resources on the Internet) and you will need sometimes (depending of your implementation) to accept this certificate in order to make a successful connection.

You can combine it, of course, with using password protected files.